# Botones "Siguiente y Anterior"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tardes, soy un poco novato en el tema y tengo una aplicación para hacer tests el cual tiene dos botones para ir a la siguiente pregunta y para ir hacia atrás si se quiere. El caso es que no tengo manera de cuadrarlos bien ya que si la pregunta es muy larga, se ponen donde quieren. Por otro lado me gustaría saber si se podrían poner dos flechas a ambos lados del form para hacer la misma función. Gracias,

```css
header{
 background: #000033;
 height: 70px;
 color:#fff;
}
a{text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}
header p{padding-top:20px;}
footer{
 background: #339966;
 height: 100px;
 color:#fff;
}
footer p{padding-top:50px;}
.image{
 padding-top:10%;
 height: 453px;
}
.intro{
 margin:150px 0px 150px 70px;
}
.question{height: 342px;}
.result-logo{margin-left: 42%;margin-top:1.6%;}
.result-logo1{margin-left: 55%;}
.result-container{margin-left: 40%;margin-top:1%; color:#684B68;}
.logout{padding-top:100px;}
.next{margin-left:200px;}
.answer{color:green;font-weight: 300;font-size: larger; }
.answerw{color:#F00;font-weight: 300;font-size: larger; }
.result{height: 452px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0">-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <script src="js/promise.min.js"></script>


  <style>
   .container {
    margin-top: 110px;
   }
   .error {
    color: #B94A48;
   }
   .form-horizontal {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
   }
   .hide{display: none;}
  </style>
     
 </head>
 <body style="background-color:#EEE">
     <header>
            <p class="text-center">
                Bienvenid@ 
            </p>
        </header>
        
  <div class="container question">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
    
    <hr>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="result.php">
                                           
                    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
 
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
                 
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                   <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>  
                   
                    <br/>
                    <div id="botones">
                    <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Siguiente</button>
                    </div>
   
                    </div>     
                      
                     <?php }elseif($i<1 || $i<$rows){?>
                       <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
     
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
                   
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>      
                                                                           
                    <br/>
     <div id="botones">
                    <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button>                    
                    <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Siguiente</button>
                   </div>
                    </div>
                    
                      
                         
                   <?php }elseif($i==$rows){?>
                    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                    
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>. <?php echo $result['question_name'];?></p>
                    
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer1'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer2'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer3'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/> <?php echo $result['answer4'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/>
                    <div id="botones">
                    <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button>                    
                    <button id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Terminar</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
     <?php } $i++;} ?>
      
    </form>
   </div>
  
        </div>
        <div class="container question">
       <footer>
            <p class="text-center" id="foot">
                Footer
            </p>
       </footer>
       </div>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: El código HTML parece no ser válido (p.e. se cierran `div` que no se han abierto o al revés, y va a haber IDs repetidos). Además, sería más útil si compartieses el código generado (en lugar del PHP) y el CSS, así sería un [mcve] y sería más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Creo que ya está

Comment: Eso sigue siendo PHP y no el código HTML generado. Sólo con el código que compartes es imposible saber qué está fallando, necesitas compartir el HTML y el CSS que afecte a los botones para poder ver el fallo.

Comment: No estaría mal formatear bien el código que pongas además de lo que ya te comentan.

Comment: Buenos días, perdonad pero ayer me fue imposible... acabo de editar la pregunta. El tema también es que si la pregunta es muy larga, se sobrepone el footer con el div del content... por lo visto la estructura no la tengo bien. Gracias.

Comment: Añade la etiqueta css a la pregunta, que tendrás más ayuda así.

Comment: Gracias @pablo.

Comment: Te recomiendo eliminar todo el código PHP del ejemplo y, de esa manera, ofrecer un [MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) con el que trabajar. Facilitará mucho el trabajo de los que te ayuden. Voy a editar la pregunta para introducirlo dentro de un fragmento de código para que sea más fácil de probar.

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por contestar. En el código que has puesto arriba, si te fijas, el div sigue comiéndose el footer.

Comment: Yo no he puesto ningún código. Es el tuyo. Sólo lo he metido dentro de un control que permite previsualizar tu código. Si limpias el código PHP de él podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Con mucho trabajo de limpieza he conseguido emular un test con dos preguntas, espero que lo que te recomiendo sea lo que estás buscando. Lo de cambiar de pregunta no sé cómo reproducirlo porque necesitaría un MCVE real y no hecho por mí (que no sé cómo quieres conseguirlo).

Comment: He descubierto otro problema de diseño, que quizá esté relacionado con el que planteas (y no podré verificarlo hasta que no nos proporciones un MCVE). Seguiré intentando corregir los defectos que vea, aunque sigo sin entender lo que quieres decir con poner los botones de siguiente y anterior a ambos lados del formulario. ¿Te refieres a ambos lados de cada pregunta? ¿Del listado completo de preguntas?

Comment: Perfecto @OscarGarcia... funciona! Muchás gracias por todo el esfuerzo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espero que esto sea lo que buscas.

Si haces flotar el botón a la derecha (`float: right`) podrás mantenerlo en la misma línea que el que se queda a la izquierda. También puedes usar `pull-right`, pero se quedaría pegado a la derecha del botón que está a la izquierda, equivale a un `float: right !important;`.

```css
header{
 background: #000033;
 height: 70px;
 color:#fff;
}
a{text-decoration: none;color: #fff;}
header p{padding-top:20px;}
footer{
 background: #339966;
 height: 100px;
 color:#fff;
}
footer p{padding-top:50px;}
.image{
 padding-top:10%;
 height: 453px;
}
.intro{
 margin:150px 0px 150px 70px;
}
/* O gestionas el exceso de ese tamaño o lo quitas */
/*.question {
  height: 342px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}*/
.result-logo{margin-left: 42%;margin-top:1.6%;}
.result-logo1{margin-left: 55%;}
.result-container{margin-left: 40%;margin-top:1%; color:#684B68;}
.logout{padding-top:100px;}
/* O pones esto */
.next{float: right;}
/* O pruebas a poner la clase "pull-right" */
.answer{color:green;font-weight: 300;font-size: larger; }
.answerw{color:#F00;font-weight: 300;font-size: larger; }
.result{height: 452px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- ¡¡OJO!! Esto no puedo meterlo aquí -->
    <script src="js/promise.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .container {
        margin-top: 110px;
      }
      .error {
        color: #B94A48;
      }
      .form-horizontal {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
      }
      .hide{display: none;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#EEE">
    <header>
      <p class="text-center">Bienvenid@</p>
    </header>
    <div class="container question">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
        <hr/>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='login' method="post" action="result.php">                               
          <div id='question1' class='cont'>
            <p class='questions' id="qname1">1. ¿Cuál es la primera pregunta?</p>
            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_1' name='1'/> Respuesta 1<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_1' name='1'/> Respuesta 2<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_1' name='1'/> Respuesta 3<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_1' name='1'/> Respuesta 3<br/>
            <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_1' name='1'/><br/>
            <div id="botones">
              <button id='1' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button>
              <button id='1' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Siguiente</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id='question2' class='cont'>
            <p class='questions' id="qname2">2. ¿Cuál es la segunda pregunta?</p>
            <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_2' name='2'/> Respuesta 1<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_2' name='2'/> Respuesta 2<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_2' name='2'/> Respuesta 3<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_2' name='2'/> Respuesta 3<br/>
            <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_2' name='2'/><br/>
            <div id="botones">
              <button id='1' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button>
              <button id='1' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Siguiente</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container question">
      <footer>
        <p class="text-center" id="foot">Footer</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  <body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html>
```

Edito: Ya he entendido lo que decías acerca del pie de página. Como has forzado una altura del bloque contenedor de todas las preguntas, cuando las preguntas superan dicho tamaño tu pie de página se descuadra. Si no fuerzas la alta del bloque (o usas, por ejemplo, `min-height` en su lugar) ese problema desaparecerá.

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar las flechas puedes utilizar los iconos de Bootstrap:

[Da clic para ver glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utiliza el siguiente `tag` de `html`:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
```

o las clases que muestro acontinuación en casi cualquier control de `html`:

```
glyphicon glyphicon-[nombre del icono]
```

```css
header {
  background: #000033;
  height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
header p {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
footer {
  background: #339966;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}
footer p {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.image {
  padding-top: 10%;
  height: 453px;
}
.intro {
  margin: 150px 0px 150px 70px;
}
.question {
  height: 342px;
}
.result-logo {
  margin-left: 42%;
  margin-top: 1.6%;
}
.result-logo1 {
  margin-left: 55%;
}
.result-container {
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  color: #684B68;
}
.logout {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
/* O pones esto */

.next {
  float: right;
}
/* O pruebas a poner la clase "pull-right" */

.answer {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: larger;
}
.answerw {
  color: #F00;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: larger;
}
.result {
  height: 452px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id='1' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Anterior</button>
<button id='1' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Siguiente</button>


<br/>
<br/>Para agregar las flechas solo es necesario usar los iconos de bootstrap <b>glyphicon</b>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id='1' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  Anterior
</button>
<button id='1' class='next btn btn-success chevron-right' type='button'>
  Siguiente
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>


<br/>
<br/>

<button id='1' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  
</button>
<button id='1' class='next btn btn-success chevron-right' type='button'>
  
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías Intentar es hacer una paginación de tus preguntas de tal manera que se muestre cuantas han respondido y cuantas son las faltantes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  </head>
    <body>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></body></html>
```

Como resultado obtendrias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]